# How to fix Gmail keyboard shortcut that stops working in Chrome?

Tags: macos, keyboard, gmail, google-chrome

The Gmail keyboard shortcuts are generally excellent. One of them (⌘-Shift-7 to start an ordered list) seems to work for me for a while after restarting Chrome… then stops working. I note that the others keep working (so ⌘-Shift-8 to start an unordered list and ⌘-Shift-9 to start a block quote always work).

And ideas on how to track down why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you check if this also happens with other OSes? I suspect this might be a Gmail/Chrome issue, and not an OS X one. It's quite appalling when Gmail doesn't work properly on Chrome!

Comment: I don't use an other desktop OSes regularly enough to get the problem to occur. It's not 100% reproducible on OS X as it is.

Comment: Do you have any installed extensions? If so, try disabling them to see if that solves the problem.